# NMAP com PHP - Mostrar resultado do NMAP em tabela dentro do navegador

Tags: php, html

Após fazer scan com NMAP, estou tentando criar uma tabela com as seguintes colunas:

```
ITEM | PORTA | PROTOCOLO | ESTADO | SERVIÇO
```

sendo pra cada coluna um resultado do NMAP:
item: o indice do vetor
porta: o numero da porta (antes do barra)
protocolo: tipo de protocolo (depois da barra)
estado: estado do serviço se aberto ou fechado
serviço: qual aplicação esta rodando

Fazendo scan local minha saida fica assim:

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  string(22) "PORT     STATE SERVICE"
  [1]=>
  string(18) "21/tcp   open  ftp"
  [2]=>
  string(19) "80/tcp   open  http"
  [3]=>
  string(26) "139/tcp  open  netbios-ssn"
  [4]=>
  string(27) "445/tcp  open  microsoft-ds"
  [5]=>
  string(20) "3306/tcp open  mysql"
  [6]=>
  string(25) "5432/tcp open  postgresql"
}
```

Como ficaria o algoritmo pra transformar esse vetor em uma tabela dentro do HTML?

Segue código pra análise

```
<?php
$host = $_POST["host"];
$saida = shell_exec('nmap -P0 ' . $host);
$vetorLinhas = explode("\n", $saida);
$start = array_keys(preg_grep('/^PORT/', $vetorLinhas))[0];
$data = array_slice($vetorLinhas, $start, -3)
?>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Projeto Integrador de Tecnologia</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5">Scanner de Porta TCP/UDP</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td height="60" colspan="5" align="center"> 
                    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="index.php">
                        <br/><br/><br/>
                        Endereço de Host
                        <label for="textfield"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="host" id="textfield" placeholder="Digite o host aqui" />
                        <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Ir" />
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td height="60" colspan="5">
                    <?php if ($_POST["host"]) { ?>
                        <pre>
                            <?php
                            $ctt = count($data);
                            for ($i = 0; $i < $ctt; $i++) {//for
                            }

                            foreach ($data as $key => $value) {//foreach
                            }

                            echo "<pre><br/>";
                            var_dump($data);
                            ?>
                        </pre>
                    <?php } ?>
                </td>
            </tr>          
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Esta pergunta foi duplicada porque a moderação ordenou que não fizesse pergunta no mesmo tópico criado anteriormente e ordenou que fosse feita uma nova pergunta justamente porque a resposta foi parcialmente satisfatória